# Google Analytics ignoring pageview

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a strange bug with Google Analytics.

For watching data I`m using realtime report.

When I open page like 
http://example.com/?**r1**=1&utm_source=test1&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=test2 - this data will not shown on GA realtime report.

If I will open page like http://example.com/?**d1**=1&utm_source=test1&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=test2 - I will find it in my GA account.

Why I cant use r1 (r2, r10, r123456 not working too)? It is any reserved variable? How I can correct it? I need to user ?r1.

UPDATE:
I checked JS-console, and found: prntscr.com/40beio 
This error: prntscr.com/40bez3

UPDATE2:
prntscr.com/40brus - error in opera

Comment: This is certainly not a problem with Analytics. I would guess your website produces unexpected output when the r1 parameter is present that mangles the Google javascript code. Can you share the url ?

Comment: Yes it was our problem.